# Community - MyPage.ImageGallery is always null

Tags: episerver

whenever I try to get the user myPage, the ImageGallery for that myPage is always null because of which I am not able to add a potrait and update myPage. Below is my code.

```cs
Image portraitImage = new Image(null, imageName, String.Empty, author, memoryStream);
portraitImage.Status = EntityStatus.Approved;
// Update the user's my page with the new image
MyPage myPage = (MyPage)MyPageHandler.Instance.GetMyPage(commonUser).CreateWritableClone();
myPage.Portrait = portraitImage;
MyPageHandler.Instance.UpdateMyPage(myPage);
```

`MyPageHandler.Instance.UpdateMyPage(myPage)` always throws an error saying myPage.ImageGallery is null.

Answer (score 1):

You do not set the `ImageGallery` property anywhere in your code. The only property you set is `Portrait`

```cs
myPage.Portrait = portraitImage;
```

Comment: ImageGallery property can not be set because it is only a get property.

I also tried using CreateImageGallery extension from MyPageHandler but even that doesn't seems to be working for me.

According to my knowledge a default instance of ImageGallery is always associated with MyPage, and it should never throw a null exception.

Please provide some sample code if you have any.